# DATE Conversion - Gregorian to Hijr in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Im trying  Gregorian date  to Hijr dates

i have this in excel but this format is not working in google sheeet please anyone know how can i format  Gregorian to Hijr in google sheet

```
[$-,117]B2dd-mm-yyyy;@
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to be possible with automatic formatting. Perhaps you can do something with this?https://www.jostrans.org/issue17/art_darani.php#:~:text=Year%20Gregorian%20%3D%20Year%20Muslim%20%C3%97,Gregorian%E2%80%93%20622)%20%C3%97%201.03.

Comment: As there is no way to do it using Sheets formulas. I think an Apps Script custom formula would be your best option. How do you want the output date to be formatted?

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution

=VLOOKUP(A2;IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bRjd8tBXujn4C1pMi5onqLS8CUQ_Wp9IkW2OkgFQ2nU";"HijriDates!$A$1:$D");3;0)

A2: the date you are looking for